# Give some fields more relevance and sort by relevance in mysql full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance

I have two fields in posts table - **post_title** and **post_content**. Now I use standard full text search to match some keywords against both fields. I need to give the title field more relevance than the content field and than order the results by relevance...

What would the mysql syntax look like to achieve this goal? I use mysql 5.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, create three FULLTEXT indexes:

```
* one on the title column
* one on the body column
* one on both title and body columns
```

Then, build your query in the following manner:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, title, body,
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('word_to_search') AS rel_title,
MATCH (body) AGAINST ('word_to_search') AS rel_body
FROM table_to_use
WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('word_to_search')
ORDER BY (rel_title*2)+(rel_body)
```

This will give the title 2 times more relevance than the body.

This is quite handy when you need to allow the content to be sorted, for instance, by tags (which are not viewed by the users) because it allows you to tweak the results from behind the scenes.

Comment: Gave you a thumb up .. but still I don't like 3 indexes......just don't like it...

Comment: Whats the cost of this operation? we are matching again and again!!

Comment: Hi Pham, could say why you do not like it and if so, then how to improve it?

Comment: Hi Raheel, it's costly as all is done in the database. You could take all the data and do it in code. You have any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: It's again a trade-off. Requirements vs Performance :| thanks for the answer!