# mysql fulltext columns priority

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

How can I set priority for multiple columns in mysql fulltext search ?

```
SELECT ID, POSITION, DATA, DATE_FORMAT(DATA, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE 
FROM VACANCIES 
WHERE VACANCIES.VISIBLE = '1' 
AND MATCH(POSITION, REQUITEMENST) AGAINST('mysql') 
AND MATCH(POSITION, REQUITEMENST) AGAINST('php') 
ORDER BY DATE(DATA) DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

I need to get first results matched column POSITION, then REQUITEMENST

Comment: Duplicate question.  See a great answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767145/give-some-fields-more-relevance-and-sort-by-relevance-in-mysql-full-text-search